# Stuck connecting to remote SOAP service with credentials

Tags: wcf, soap, binding, soapui, wcf-binding

I need to connect to a remote SOAP service. For several days that I have been trying <s>all the</s> many configurations without success.

Connection is OK when using SoapUI. 
Connection is KO when calling from my .net application.

Errors : ***The username is not provided. Specify username in ClientCredentials.***

My application and the remote application are both running on IIS.

Here is the remote binding :

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WsHttpBinding_Default" maxReceivedMessageSize="524288000" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" establishSecurityContext="false" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

SoapUI works with the following configuration :

- Authorization : Basic
- Username: DOMAIN\username
- Password : pwd
- Pre-Emptive authentication

When I check the raw request from SoapUI, it's sending this :

```
POST https://domain.name/TestNode/V_ServicePartenaireDS/v5.svc HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="http://URI/getUser"
Authorization: Basic UEFSVFxzdmMtaWlzYmsdfsdfsdfphZG1pbjEyMy0t
Content-Length: 1371
Host: proxy-int.part.lan.net
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:v2="http://cnc.fr/Circe/Partenaires/v2.7">
    <soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="true" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-268FDC1861EA4F5F3C154297086643492">
                <wsu:Created>2018-11-23T11:01:06Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2018-11-23T16:34:26Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-268FDC1861EA4F5F3C154297086643491">
                <wsse:Username>PART\svc-iisbackend</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">pwd</wsse:Password>
                <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">yi71/jQzUJw/lzReixSgOA==</wsse:Nonce>
                <wsu:Created>2018-11-23T11:01:06.434Z</wsu:Created>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
        <wsa:Action>http://UIR/getUser</wsa:Action>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <v2:getUser>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <v2:id>200785</v2:id>
        </v2:getUser>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Everything above is **working**.

---

Now, what am I doing in my .net 4.6.1 application ? I am trying to send the same request that SoapUI is sending.

Here is how I do : web.config with endpoints, bindings and behaviour extension. The extended behaviour implements an EndPoint Behaviour that calls an Inspector (from ApplyClientBehavior) from which I use the BeforeSendRequest to add two things :

- a SOAP header  `<wsse:Security />`
- a Authorization: Basic http header.

Here are the details of the implementation.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WsHttpBinding_Default" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
                </security>
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
            </binding>
            <binding name="WsHttpBinding_Authentication" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
                </security>
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttp_Default" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <extensions>
        <behaviorExtensions>
            <add name="localSecurity" type="Users.UsersImplementation.Service.ImplementationCommon.BehaviorExtensionBasicAuthent, Users.UsersImplementation"/>
        </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="LocalWsBehavior">
                <callbackDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />  
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
                <localSecurity/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://domain/TestNode/V_ServiceUser/v5.svc" behaviorConfiguration="LocalWsBehavior" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WsHttpBinding_Authentication" contract="App.UserDSContract.IServiceUserDS" name="" />
        <!--<headers>
          <wsse:Security xmlns:soap="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope" soap:mustUnderstand="true" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-268FDC1861EA4F5F3C154289160250080">
              <wsu:Created>2018-11-22T15:15:02Z</wsu:Created>
              <wsu:Expires>2018-11-22T18:33:22Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-268FDC1861EA4F5F3C154289160250079">
              <wsse:Username>PART\svc-iisbackend</wsse:Username>
              <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">pws</wsse:Password>
              <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">NcDsjgc1/cRNuHVMR7kJBw==</wsse:Nonce>
              <wsu:Created>2018-11-22T15:15:02.499Z</wsu:Created>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
          </wsse:Security>
        </headers>
      </endpoint>-->        
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Down the chain of c# class, we find this code :

```
    void IClientMessageInspector.AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        // nothing to do here
    }

    object IClientMessageInspector.BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        SoapSecurityHeader header = new SoapSecurityHeader("PART\\svc-iisbackend", "pwd");
        request.Headers.Add(header);
        HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestMessage;
        object httpRequestMessageObject;
        if (request.Properties.TryGetValue(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, out httpRequestMessageObject))
        {
            httpRequestMessage = httpRequestMessageObject as HttpRequestMessageProperty;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(httpRequestMessage.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization]))
            {
                httpRequestMessage.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("PART\\svc-iisbackend-sagre" + ":" + "admin123--")); 
            }
            request.Properties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, httpRequestMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
            httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("PART\\svc-iisbackend-sagre" + ":" + "admin123--")));
            request.Properties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, httpRequestMessage);
        }
        return header.Id;
    }
```

The resulting SOAP envelope at the remote server side* is this :

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://UIR/getUser</a:Action>
        <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:2b66b328-778f-4967-925a-01b75d9ab607</a:MessageID>
        <a:ReplyTo>
            <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
        </a:ReplyTo>
        <wsse:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-f7abfe27c28e4209b8c028ef78bdf739">
                <wsu:Created>2018-11-23T14:37:46.59Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2018-11-23T16:37:46.59Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-aff0ea1c178c4843babf4afa5cd280f6">
                <wsse:Username>PART\svc-iisbackend</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">pwd</wsse:Password>
                <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">qdiFSufkRLuPRHTwDYPzBDTu1/o=</wsse:Nonce>
                <wsu:Created>2018-11-23T14:37:46.593Z</wsu:Created>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://domain.url/V_ServiceUser/v5.svc</a:To>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <getUser xmlns="http://url">
            <id>200472</id>
        </getUser>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I have followed many blog and documentation to make it until this point and I am still stuck :D

*To get the message to hit the server I need to use the default binding configuration WsHttpBinding_Default. When I am using the WsHttpBinding_Authentication the request does not seem to be processed by the remote server.

I tried to play with the bindings configuration but no luck so far.

- What is wrong with my current configuration ?
- With WsHttpBinding_Authentication  I got the said error (edited : wrong error copied pasted)<s>The username is not provided. Specify username in ClientCredentials.</s> An error occurred when verifying security for the message.
- With WsHttpBinding_Default, the remote server processed a bit of the request and reject it with the following error :

the error :

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault</a:Action>
        <a:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:2b66b328-778f-4967-925a-01b75d9ab607</a:RelatesTo>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
            <s:Code>
                <s:Value>s:Sender</s:Value>
                <s:Subcode>
                    <s:Value xmlns:a="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">a:InvalidSecurity</s:Value>
                </s:Subcode>
            </s:Code>
            <s:Reason>
                <s:Text xml:lang="fr-FR">Une erreur s'est produite lors de la vérification de la sécurité du message.</s:Text>
            </s:Reason>
        </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Sorry for the wall of text, I hope everything needed to get a clear view of my issue is here. 
Many thanks for having read so far :)

Edit : as you can see I also tried to put the header directly in the xml endpoint but no success so far.

Edit : The calling binding was wrong, it is now  :

```
<binding name="WsHttpBinding_Authentication" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
```

With that new binding my error is now :

```
{"globalErrors":["Message with Action 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/SCT' is unknown and cannot be forwarded to the recipient. This may happen if message Action was changed, or if operation was disabled or deleted from the service contract."]}
```

I find no content about this error, what is happening :/

Edit : Solved the error by re-adding `establishSecurityContext="false"` in the binding.

Edit : To add credentials I am using that post answers : [Set WCF ClientCredentials in App.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725294/set-wcf-clientcredentials-in-app-config)

It seems to work, I am making progress toward an old error : `An error occurred when verifying security for the message.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !!!

So much frustration, but writing a SO post and keeping it updated helped a lot.

I go celebrated and I will come back to detail the solution.

In short, use the implementation from the link I add in my edits, not my previous way.

Answer (score 0):

To add a username and password to the Service, you would need to do the following when setting up the service

```
// Instantiate the proxy  
Service1Client proxy = new Service1Client();

// Set the user’s credentials on the proxy  
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = username;  
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;
```

This is when you are using standard WS username and password, I have added an answer to my own question after experiencing the exact same thing as well, The link is [WCF Service inside aspnet webforms throwing 302](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52698281/wcf-service-inside-aspnet-webforms-throwing-302/53393462#53393462)

You can read up more on from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-authenticate-with-a-user-name-and-password)

Comment: I can't do that, I have no proxy or serviceclient in my code.

Comment: How do you instantiate your service then?

Comment: With a unity container registering the remote service and injections

Comment: Can you show the bit of code where you tie your service with the EndpointBehavior?